# Bluetooth Headphones are Paired but Cannot Connect without Rediscovering

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a Windows 10 machine and Sony Bluetooth headphones.

I can pair them as usual, and after pairing them I can connect them and play music on them as usual.

After restarting or waking from sleep, the headphones stay paired in the Bluetooth devices.  There is a button to connect them, but whenever I do that Windows says it can't find them.  I have to make the headphones discoverable again and pair them again every time.

This is only true of my Windows 10 machine.  My phones and tablets have all been able to reconnect to these headphones without needing to pair them again.

Others have had this problem (like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1147989/bluetooth-device-paired-but-not-connected)), but there is no solution there to my problem.  (Going through the action center every time is also inconvenient, and though I haven't tested it, I have no reason to think it would work there but not in the Bluetooth settings window).

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I don't connect the bluetooth to any other device, then it will be connectable to my PC as usual.  It's only if I switch to playing from my phone or tablet or other computer, and then switch back to the PC that this happens.  But Windows 7 doesn't have a problem connecting under the same conditions that Win10 fails.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a widespread issue. Check this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/bluetooth-volume-broken-after-windows-10-1803/b966b86f-626d-4dbe-8043-5f0f2901c354

Comment: Thanks for sending that, but the issue is different and I didn't see any solution there either, just lots of people with the problem.

Comment: The issue isn't exactly the same, but I have been looking on the web and there seem to be a few threads talking about issues with connecting/pairing and Bluetooth audio devices as a whole. My guess is that the change in the way Bluetooth devices are managed in Build 1803 caused many problems, so we will have to wait for a fix, unfortunately.